# Query regarding SSL_connect and HTTPS

Tags: sockets, https, openssl, network-programming, http-proxy

I wanted send an HTTPS request through a proxy server and obtain the HTML of the landing page of the site. The socket creation went smoothly but when i wanted to make an SSL connection to the server it gave me a **"Aborted (Core Dumped)"** error. I've narrowed the cause down to the **SSL_connect** function. When i tried to do the same without the proxy server (using struct addrinfo instead of struct sockaddr since I needed to make a DNS query to get the IP), it worked perfectly and I was able to get a valid HTTP response along with the HTML. Can someone help me out ?

```
        SSL_library_init();
        SSL_load_error_strings();
        ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method ());

        int sockfd2 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        struct sockaddr_in httpsProxy; 
    
        httpsProxy.sin_family = AF_INET;
        httpsProxy.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("<insert IP>");
        httpsProxy.sin_port = htons(13128);
        connect(sockfd2,(struct sockaddr *)&httpsProxy,sizeof(httpsProxy));
    
        SSL *conn = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
        SSL_set_fd(conn, sockfd2);
        int err = SSL_connect(conn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect to the proxy and request it to connect to the target HTTPS server, **without** using SSL/TLS yet while communicating with the proxy, and only if successful THEN perform the SSL/TLS handshake via `SSL_connect()` once you are communicating with the HTTPS server, not with the proxy anymore.

```
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();

int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in httpsProxy = {};
httpsProxy.sin_family = AF_INET;
httpsProxy.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("<proxy IP>");
httpsProxy.sin_port = htons(13128);

// connect to proxy...
if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&httpsProxy, sizeof(httpsProxy)) < 0)
{
    ...
    close(sockfd);
    return;
}

// ask proxy to connect to target HTTPS server...
if (!<connect proxy to HTTPS server>)
{
    ...
    close(sockfd);
    return;
}

// NOW start SSL/TLS with HTTPS server...
ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method ());
SSL *conn = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
SSL_set_fd(conn, sockfd);
int err = SSL_connect(conn);
...
```

Comment: my task includes handling HTTP redirects with HTTPS requests from the proxy server exclusively (part of assignment). I was able to get HTML of the sites which are still on HTTP via the proxy server with no problem. Based on the status code of the HTTP response (30x in this case) I am creating a  new socket and encapsulating with an SSL layer and sending HTTPS request to the proxy server. I am not allowed to direcltly request the web server of the target site. So, is there any other way to do this or am I missing the point here ? Thanks so much

Comment: @SilentGuardian What kind of proxy are you working with exactly? An HTTP proxy? A SOCKS proxy? Please be more specific. It makes a BIG difference in how you have to approach this issue. But the secure way to send requests to an HTTPS server through a proxy is how I describe in my answer. The HTTP redirect will tell you where you need to instruct the proxy to connect on the new connection.

Comment: I am working with HTTP proxy and understood what you were explaining just now. Problem is resolved. Thank you so much